# ((PtrToStruct)*(unsigned int*)ADDRESS)

Tags: c, ram

Before I asked I have research similar question. The most closet is this:
https://www.careercup.com/forumpost?id=5752438032171008

But I still don't understand, what is the meaning of this code?

```
((PtrToStruct)*(unsigned int*)ADDRESS)
```

Here is original code format:

```
typedef struct __st_vec{
    member 1
    ...
    ...
    ...
    member n
}VEC, *PVEC;

#define ADDRESS 0x2000
#define VEC_PLACE() ((PVEC)*(unsigned int*)ADDRESS)
```

then somewhere in code can use it to get member data in struct

```
variable = VEC_PLACE()->member 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is very specific HW oriented.

It actually assumes that the address of data structure of type `VEC` is stored ar `ADDRESS` and the size of address/pointer is `sizeof(unsigned int)`.

```
((PVEC)*(unsigned int*)ADDRESS)
```

==> `(unsigned int*)ADDRESS`  -- use value `ADDRESS` as a pointer to `unsigned int`

==> `*(unsigned int*)ADDRESS` -- *dereference it* (*read* `sizeof(unsigned int)` bytes from the address `ADDRESS`).

==> `(PVEC)*(unsigned int*)ADDRESS` -- use/treat this dereferenced value as a pointer (address) to the structure `VEC`

Comment: Thank you for response so detail in every operation in this line.
I understand this right now, but still not able to write this kind of code, need learning XD

Comment: @junchen you are welcome. Don't worry, it's a matter of practice and experience. You will get to it too.

Comment: @junchen if it answers your question you can chose one of the given answers as the "accepted" one by clicking on the V near the voting buttons

Comment: I would say far more likely, this code is bugged and should not be used. If it does what you think it do, it should have been written as `*(volatile VEC*)*(volatile uintptr_t*)ADDRESS`. Though more likely, the person who wrote the code goofed up in several ways and it is actually meant to be `*(volatile VEC*)ADDRESS`.

Comment: @Lundin Bugged?.. it depends... for example if it is a firmware/embedded code which always reads the configuration structure at the predefined address during init flow (power on/after reset) then the `volatile` keyword is not required since the data is already there and it is static.

Comment: @AlexLop. That's fairly exotic though, some sort of fake memory mapping running on top of a bootloader. Far more likely, they intended to access memory-mapped registers directly.

Answer (score 1):

Many hardware systems have memory mapped registers, places where they store or read data. On small embedded direct-to-hardware systems it's common that those registers are placed in fixed locations, i.e. addresses.

What the macro does is basically allow access in a nicer way to such a location, instead of having to write all the casting and dereferencing each and every time.

---

More specifically, on the location of `ADDRESS` (`0x2000`) there seems to be stored a pointer to a structure of type `VEC`.

With `(unsigned int*)ADDRESS` the macro pretends that the value of `ADDRESS` is really a pointer to `unsigned int`. The macro then dereference that pointer, to get the value stored in memory at `ADDRESS`. Lastly, this value is then converted to a pointer to `VEC`.

Comment: Thank you for response patiently, I got the point!!
I still need to learning XD